# COMBINE TWO ARRAYS ONE AS KEY AND OTHER AS VALUE IN ANGULAR JS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have two arrays.

```
dat=['name','value','sub','mark']

dat1=[['mmm','lll','jjj','99'],['ccc','ccc','vvv','55']];
```

I need an like this

```
 $scope.alldata = [{name : mmm, value : lll, sub:jjj, mark :99}, {name : ccc, value : ccc, sub:vvv, mark :55}]
```

In php we can do it with array_combine.
But I need it in angular js.
Please help me..

Comment: `for (i=0; i<key.length; i++) new_array[keys[i]] = values[i]`

Comment: can you please expand this code.. I have tried similar to this,.. but some error i got..

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Array#forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and an object for populating the result.

```js
var dat = ['name', 'value', 'sub', 'mark'],
    dat1 = [['mmm', 'lll', 'jjj', '99'], ['ccc', 'ccc', 'vvv', '55']],
    result = dat1.map(function (a) {
        var o = {};
        dat.forEach(function (k, i) {
            o[k] = a[i];
        })
        return o;
    });

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use `Array#reduce` in the callback of `Array#map`

```js
var dat = ['name', 'value', 'sub', 'mark'],
  dat1 = [
    ['mmm', 'lll', 'jjj', '99'],
    ['ccc', 'ccc', 'vvv', '55']
  ],
  op = dat1.map(function(item) {
    return item.reduce(function(a, b, index) {
      a[dat[index]] = item[index];
      return a;
    }, {})
  });
console.log(op);
```